# Polygon in specific size

Tags: qgis, polygon, area

I have the task of inserting a polygon in a map with a specific size. My idea is to simply "draw" a polygon and keep on enhacing its size, until it reaches the size I actually want to be. Its basically an easy task, but i'm wondering if i could directly have the polygon in the size i want it to be. I went through the vector-tools, but nothing seemed to do the trick.
I'm using QGIS 2.18.3 (Las Palmas)

Comment: what sort of polygon? size as length or area?

Comment: area!The polygon doesnt even have to have a specific shape...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [QAD Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qad/) to draw a regular polygon with a specific area. For example, if you want to draw a polygon with an area of 50000 square meter you can do the following:

1. Select regular polygon as you can see below:
   [image]
2. Specify the number of edges at the command line below (I chose 6), and click enter
   [image]
3. Specify Center of the polygon or Edge: clicked on target position on the screen
4. Enter an option `[Inscibed in Circle/Circumscribed about circle/Area]`: Choose Area 
   [image]
5. Enter the polygon area: Choose the specific area you want, 50000 for example

[image]

Comment: This works! I'm still struggeling with the area, there is a gap between what i insert and what i calculate (for verification), but i'm sure its a small issue which is manageable! Thanks

Comment: The QAD plugin is not compatible with v3.xxx

Answer (score 1):

If it does not need to be QGIS have a try with OpenJUMP. With the Draw circle tool you can define the size and then create circles of fixed size with just one click.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply. We dont have OpenJUMP at work. I will look into it anyway

Comment: The normal Draw polygon tool shows the area in real time when you draw a new feature but unfortunately the other circle tool that is used by dragging the circle to the desired size shows only perimeter in real time.

Comment: Hi, I can't chose the number of side I want for my polygon, neither the size with QAD... can you explain how did you do?

Comment: Did you notice this is OpenJUMP? My answer was using the Draw circle with given radius and center from the standard toolbox. It does not have a direct input for the number of sides. Accuracy has an indirect effect but does not allow to draw triangles, for example. There is indeed a special tool in the CAD toolbox "Draw regular concyclic polygon" that takes radius and number of sides as input. The result is a closed linestring but it can be converted into polygon easily. I tried and had no problem with using that CAD tool. Just select the tool, fill in the parameters, and click on the map.